# Subsequent requests from postgres client

Tags: postgresql, network-programming

Does Postgres client support sending subsequent requests without receiving response? If so, how does the client correlate between a request and its response from the server?

Comment: See the libpq documentation on pipeline mode https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pipeline-mode.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is possible; see the [documentation of the frontend-backend protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-PIPELINING):

> Use of the extended query protocol allows pipelining, which means sending a series of queries without waiting for earlier ones to complete. This reduces the number of network round trips needed to complete a given series of operations. However, the user must carefully consider the required behavior if one of the steps fails, since later queries will already be in flight to the server.
>
> [...]
>
> The extended query protocol provides another way to manage this concern, which is to omit sending Sync messages between steps that are dependent. Since, after an error, the backend will skip command messages until it finds Sync, this allows later commands in a pipeline to be skipped automatically when an earlier one fails, without the client having to manage that explicitly with BEGIN and COMMIT. Independently-committable segments of the pipeline can be separated by Sync messages.

Recent versions of PostgreSQL have support for that in the C API, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pipeline-mode.html). I don't think that the JDBC driver has support for pipeline mode, but I am not certain. Recent versions of the [Python driver have support for pipeline mode](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/advanced/pipeline.html) as well.

It is easy to tell which response belongs to which statement, because the responses arrive in the same order as the statements were sent.

For some more details and a C code sample, see [my article](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pipeline-mode-better-performance-on-slow-network/).

Comment: So, pipeline mode is the only case when a client sends subsequent request without receiving the response to the previous request?

Comment: And, how does the client correlate between a request and its response from the server if it sends a new request without waiting for the response of the previous request?

Comment: Yes, this is the only way - would you need more than one way? The responses will arrive in the same order that you sent the requests, and you can send requests only one after the other, so the order of the responses is clearm isn't it?

Comment: No, I don't need any other way. I was actually making an audit tool for postgres based on a proxy server for which I needed to be certain that request and response come in order because I would decode a response packet to generate the verdict whether the request was success or failure.